# php: export database to csv, it divides columns by commas

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to export my database data into a csv file, but my problem is, that the php divides the content if a column contains a comma into two columns!
Does anyone know how to solve it?
This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $DB_ADDRESS="xxx";
    $DB_USER="xxx";
    $DB_PASS="xxx";
    $DB_NAME="xxx";

    //SETTINGS//
    //This code is something you set in the APP so random people cant use it.
    $SQLKEY="xxx";

    /************************************CONFIG****************************************/

    //these are just in case setting headers forcing it to always expire
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

    error_log(print_r($_POST,TRUE));

    if( isset($_POST['query']) && isset($_POST['key']) ){                                               //checks if the tag post is there and if its been a proper form post
     //set content type to CSV (to be set here to be able to access this page also with a browser)
      header('Content-type: text/csv');

      if($_POST['key']==$SQLKEY){                                                              //validates the SQL key
$query=urldecode($_POST['query']);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){     //check if the worthless pile of crap magic quotes is enabled and if it is, strip the slashes from the query
  $query=stripslashes($query);
}
$conn = new mysqli($DB_ADDRESS,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS,$DB_NAME);    //connect

if($conn->connect_error){                                                           //checks connection
  header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
  echo "ERROR Database Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR;   //reports a DB connection failure
} else {
  $result=$conn->query($query);                                                     //runs the posted query
  if($result === false){
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");                                             //sends back a bad request error
    echo "Wrong SQL: " . $query . " Error: " . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR;          //errors if the query is bad and spits the error back to the client
  } else {
    if (strlen(stristr($query,"SELECT"))>0) {                                       //tests if it's a SELECT statement
      $csv = '';                                                                    // bug fix Undefined variable: csv
      while ($fieldinfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
        $csv .= $fieldinfo->name.",";
      }
      $csv = rtrim($csv, ",")."\n";
      echo $csv;                                                                    //prints header row
      $csv = '';

      $result->data_seek(0);
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
          $csv .= $value.",";
        }
        $csv = rtrim($csv, ",")."\n";
      }
      echo $csv;                                                                    //prints all data rows
    } else {
      header("HTTP/1.0 201 Rows");
      echo "AFFECTED ROWS: " . $conn->affected_rows;       //if the query is anything but a SELECT, it will return the number of affected rows
    }
  }
  $conn->close();                                          //closes the DB
}
      } else {
 header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
 echo "Bad Request";                                       //reports if the secret key was bad
      }
            } else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    echo "Bad Request";
```

}
                ?>

**EDIT:** I read that I have to enclose the fields double quotes, but how can I do that?

Comment: If you used PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function rather than broken homebrew code, then you wouldn't have this problem